# Mongoose Populate - Effeciency

Tags: mongoose

I have a Product model with ref to a Category model and the following code works fine but was wondering if this is the best way of doing it.

```
server.get "/:id/edit", (req, res) ->
    Category.find({})
    .sort("position", 1)
    .exec (err, categories) ->
      if not err
        Product.findOne({_id: req.params.id })
        .populate("categories")
        .exec (err, data) ->
          if err
            res.json err
          else
            res.render "#{view_path}/products/edit",
              title: "Edit Product"
              user: req.session.user
              product: data
              categories: categories
```

Answer (score 0):

How useful using populate is greatly depends on how complex your `Category` model is and what you're using it for on the `Product` model related pages.

Generally speaking categories are a great example of something to be embedded into your products since they will change infrequently and will be pulled with the product all the time.

You may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970082/mongoose-populate-dbref-or-data-duplication) interesting. There is always quite an ongoing discussion about use cases for references or embedding.